# How to change the top bar color of browse section inside uiwebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, uicolor

I am using a uiwebview inside of a navigation controller, a user can upload a photo and permission is given the problem is in the color of the top bar as you can see in the pictures when i choose the photo library i chose a specific tint color using this code in appDelegate.swift

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = commons.getThemeColor()
```

But in the browse section the top bar and buttons are white and did not change , i tried this code to change the button color in all the pages and it did not work

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

Note that the navigation bar is set to hidden and i made a custom view as a top bar, also i tried different codes to change the titn of navigation bar

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

How can i change the color of the button or the background in the browse section.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]